# Add an exception to Joomla's .htaccess rewrite rules to allow an Owncloud subdirectory

Tags: htaccess, apache, joomla

i'm actually use Joomla in our website and i would like to add Owncloud.
The .htaccess in the root let Joomla side works without trouble:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Joomla3
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Joomla3/$1 [L]
```

But if want to access the owncloud service, i get this error:

> The requested URL /Joomla3/owncloud/ was not found on this server.

It seems the original rewrite works with the owncloud directory too.
my host is composed by 1 root directory and the 2 subdirectory:

- -root
- --Joomla
- --Owncloud

How can I set .htaccess to

1. rewrite URL from my website (example.com) into `www.example.com/Joomla`
2. access owncloud (without rewrite) in the directory `www.example.com/owncloud`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Joomla3
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Joomla3/$1 [L]
> ```

What these directives do is... if the requested URL does not start "/Joomla3" then internally rewrite the request to the "Joomla3" folder.

What you need to do is add another condition to state that... if the requested URL does not start "/Joomla3" **and it does not start "/owncloud"** then internally rewrite the request to the "Joomla3" folder.

For example, this could be achieved by adding a second `RewriteCond` (condition) directive:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Joomla3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/owncloud
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Joomla3/$1 [L]
```

`RewriteCond` directives are implicitly AND'd.

Comment: It works (for the installation part!) After that trying to access to ../owncloud, i get only "input file not specified". i guess it cannot find the right index.php file and stop processing.

Comment: update: the trick was to set cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 in php.ini configuration. now it works! :)